# What is purpose of locale setting in Java java.util.Calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar, locale

I am obtaining information (such as number of a day in week, month, year etc) about particular date in Java via java.util.Calendar. Is there some reason to set locale for calendar object in my situation? I am asking beacuse:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

returns for today (Sunday) always number 1 but in our locale (cs_CZ) it should be 7.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("cs", "CZ");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Prague");

Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz, locale);
cal.setTime(new Date());

// returns => 1 (but I expected 7)
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); 
// returns => 3 - it's OK
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

**EDIT:** I can hadle with 1 for Sunday, but I must be sure this is unchanging behaviour regardless to used Locale or TimeZone.

Comment: try to quit the cal.setTime(new Date());

Comment: @MiguelPrz - no change

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Finally I used [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(new Date());
int dayOfWeek = dt.getDayOfWeek();
```

and it returns 7 for today (Sunday).

Answer (score 10):

Locale do will affect the first day of week. However, the day values are constants, `SUNDAY` is always 1. You can check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY). The `get()` method just returns the correct field value (If it returns 7 then it's wrong -- 7 is `SATURDAY`, not the current day).

But you can call `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and it returns 2 (`MONDAY`). I think this is what you need. You can take use of these two methods to reach your goal.

```
System.out.println((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal.getFirstDayOfWeek() + 7) % 7 + 1);
```

The above statements returns 7.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me.

`Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz, locale);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());        
        cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);        
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));`

still returns 1 for today (sunday).

Comment: @user1315357 Sorry, please see the new edit. I think it was some misunderstanding, the day values are constants, only the "first day of week" will change with locales. You can also see this link: [Week start](http://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. And this does answer the OP.